# How to properly export to utf-8 csv from Access, fixing formatting issues

Tags: csv, ms-access, export-to-csv

Problem:  Want to export straight from MS Access 2016 to a UTF-8 csv file, but there are formatting problems.  File exported from Access to Excel and then manually saved as UTF-8 CSV file works correctly, but I would like to eliminate the extra  step that my user must do to create the csv file.

Layout of the CSV file is dictated by the organization we provide this data to.

We have an Access 2016 database of music CDs that we distribute.  The first column is Artist, and it is formatted last name, first name (example:  Presley, Elvis).   When saved from Excel to csv, Excel knows to format this with double quotes:  “Presley, Elvis”.
Next columns are basic info like UPC, Catalog Number, price.  These should not be surrounded by double quotes.

One column is a date, formatted in m-DDD-yy format (example 31-Dec-18).  This exports properly to Excel and when saved from Excel to UTF-8 csv, also properly formatted.

Last column is a description, which might inherently include double quotes (example:  “Elvis is a Legend,” says Jane Doe).  When saved from Excel to UTF-8 csv, this is properly converted to triple double-quotes (“””Elvis is Legend,”””).  And of course that field will need to be deliminated by double-quotes.

Back to Access, when I set up the export template, I can choose to have deliminators or not, but not conditionally.  The date can be set up as dmy but not with the three letter abbreviation; furthermore it comes out with the time stamp of 0s and the date in 4-digit year.  The system doesn’t automatically add the extra quotes around an existing quote.
I have already created a table for temporarily storing this data in access prior to exporting to excel to allow the entire description to export. Otherwise it was truncating at 255 characters.  I suppose I could make the date field a text field and save the data as the formatted text.  I suppose I could do the same with the Artist field.  The Description field is problematic.

Why does Access make it so hard, when the Excel designers have it figured out?  And is there a way to edit the export specification without going through the wizard each time, and carefully copying the export spec that I create?

The problem seems to be in the export spec.  the only actual code is:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "UTF8 Full Catalog Export Specification", "FullCatalogListing", "C:\Temp\FCLTest.csv", True, , 65001
```